# Unboundedness in $L^q$ of Fourier transform of $L^p$ function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

To show $\|\hat{f}\|_q \lesssim \|f\|_p$ does not hold for $p > 2$ where $1/p + 1/q = 1$, I was given a hint to consider a Schwartz function $\phi(\xi)$ whose support is on $B(0,1)$, and let
$$
\hat{f_N}(\xi) = \sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi in\xi_1}\phi(\xi-10ne_1).
$$
It is straightforward to see that $\|\hat{f_N}\|_q = N^{1/q}\|\phi\|_q$ since the support of $\phi(\xi-10ne_1)$ for different $n$ are disjoint. Now to show $p \le 2$, it suffices to show $\|f_N\|_p \lesssim N^{1/p}$, which after some simplification is equivalent to
$$
\bigg\|\sum_{n=1}^N e^{20\pi i nx_1}\check{\phi}(x+ne_1) \bigg\|_p^p \lesssim N.
$$
Can anyone offer some help on estimating the left hand side?

BTW I know there is another proof which is similar to this construction, and uses Khinchin's Inequality to estimate([Using Khinchin's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165169/using-khinchins-inequality)). But here we do not want to introduce the Rademacher variable.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3775866/674271 might be helpful.

Comment: I guess it’s not that relevant? Here I want to estimate the $L_p$ norm of inverse Fourier transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, each summand of $f_N(x)$ looks like a Gaussian bump of width $\sim 1$ and height $\sim 1$, centered at points that are $\sim 1$-separated, so $f_N(x)$ should look not much different than $\sum_{n=1}^N\chi_{B(0,1)}(x+ne_1)$, where $B(x,r)$ is notation for the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. Of course $\|\sum_{n=1}^N\chi_{B(0,1)}(x+ne_1)\| \sim N^{1/p}$.

Here is a sketch. Estimate,
\begin{align*}
\int|\sum_n\check\phi(x+ne_1)e^{20\pi inx_1}|^p\,dx\le \int(\sum_n|\check\phi(x+ne_1)|)^p\,dx.
\end{align*}
The key point is that for any $x\in\bigcup_{n}B(-ne_1,10)$, $\sum_n|\check\phi(x+ne_1)|$ is dominated by the contribution of at most $O(1)$ terms of the sum, and for $x\notin\bigcup_{n}B(-ne_1,10)$, you can use the smallness of the Schwartz tails. (The choice of $10$ is somewhat arbitrary, any constant $c>1$ would probably suffice, with a constant depending on $c$ hiding in the $\sim$ notation.)

Comment: Thank you Alex!